# how i add quarter in this code as my code shows days years month name etc

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 SELECT
      n AS Date_ID,
      TO_DATE('31/12/1995','DD/MM/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n,'day') AS Full_Date,
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('31/12/1995','DD/MM/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n,'day'),'DD') AS Days,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('31/12/1995','DD/MM/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n,'day'),'MM') AS Month_Num,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('31/12/1995','DD/MM/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n,'day'),'Month') AS Month,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('31/12/1995','DD/MM/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n,'day'),'YYYY') AS Year
  FROM (
   select level n
   from dual
   connect by level <= 7018)
   COMMIT;
```

Comment: All of the format model elements, including quarter (Q), [are in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A). It isn't entirely clear if that is what you're looking for though. You could include a small subset of your current output (not all 7018 rows), and what you want the output to actually be, in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('12/31/1995', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'Q') AS MY_QTR
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: NO.  ORA-01760: illegal argument for function

Comment: Sorry  @MuhammadAdil got the month and day mixed up, I edited the answer, please try now

Answer (score 0):

Expanding just a little on what @Ted showed for a single fixed date, to incorporate the quarter into you query you would do:

```
SELECT
      n AS Date_ID,
      TO_DATE('31/12/1995','DD/MM/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n,'day') AS Full_Date,
      TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('31/12/1995','DD/MM/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n,'day'),'DD') AS Days,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('31/12/1995','DD/MM/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n,'day'),'MM') AS Month_Num,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('31/12/1995','DD/MM/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n,'day'),'Month') AS Month,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('31/12/1995','DD/MM/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n,'day'),'YYYY') AS Year,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('31/12/1995','DD/MM/YYYY') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(n,'day'),'Q') AS Quarter
  FROM (
   select level n
   from dual
   connect by level <= 7018);
```

The `COMMIT` in your original is acting as a table alias for the inline view, and as it isn't referred to and has a confusing name I've removed that.

You could simplify things by doing the date manipulation once, inside that inline view:

```
select date_id,
  full_date as full_date,
  to_char(full_date, 'DD') as days,
  to_char(full_date, 'MM') as month_num,
  to_char(full_date, 'Month') as month,
  to_char(full_date, 'YYYY') as year,
  to_char(full_date, 'Q') as quarter
from (
  select level as date_id, date '1995-12-31' + level as full_date
  from dual
  connect by level <= 7018
);
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=14fb00ec683ddb700504c3e5d38b199c)

You might actually want the quarter (and maybe the year, and even the day) as numbers rather than strings; in which case just wrap those in a `to_number()` call.

You should also be aware that using the `Month` format element gives the month name in the current session language, so someone else running this with different NLS settings will see different month names. If you always want them in a specific language then you can specify that as part of that `to_char()` call.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ebbd7c0f32745b3794577bd5f630522c) with fixed language and numeric quarter.